# Vim Syntastic plugin not working for coffeescript 1.6.0+

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin, syntastic

I have the following syntastic settings inside my .vimrc:

```
"------------SYNTASTIC-----------
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
let g:syntastic_mode_map={ 'mode': 'active',
                     \ 'active_filetypes': [],
                     \ 'passive_filetypes': ['html', 'java'] }
let g:syntastic_coffee_checkers = ['coffeelint', 'coffee']
let g:syntastic_coffee_coffeelint_args = "--file [absolute path to]/coffeelint.json"
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
let g:syntastic_error_symbol='✗'
let g:syntastic_warning_symbol='⚠'
```

when I have coffeescript installed to 1.6.0+ (i.e. `npm install -g coffee-script@1.6.3`) syntastic doesn't seem able to detect any compilation errors, even though both `coffee file.coffee` and `coffeelint file.coffee` displays the error fine.

I ran `:SyntasticCheck` then `:messages` and no debug error surfaced.

I've also made sure that `npm` is part of the `PATH`: `PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"`

On the other hand, when coffeescript is installed at `coffee-script@1.5.0` the errors DO in fact surface (everything works!), except that it doesn't pick up the `coffeelint_args`. This behavior might be expect from  https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/CoffeeScript%3A---coffee

Do I need to know something special to get syntastic working w/ coffeescript 1.6.0+ on Mac?

Comment: This is a bug report, please use a more appropriate channel, like… the plugin's [issue tracker](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the issue on github: https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/694

The fix was to do a `git fetch && git rebase` or `git pull` from the syntastic git directory (assuming you're using pathogen)